# How to infer the type of a parameter based on two different interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have the following two types:

```
type one = {
    test1: string;
    test2: string;
    test3: string;
}

type two = {
    test3: string;
    test4: string;
}
```

I have a function that will accept either of the keys from the two types above:

```
function setId(
    key: keyof one | keyof two
    value:
      | one[typeof key] // ERROR HERE - Line 10
      | two[typeof key]
) {
    setField(value);
}
```

I'm getting two errors on Line 10 saying that:

> Property 'test3' does not exist on type 'one'

> Property 'test4' does not exist on type 'one'

Since the key to the `setId` function can be a key of either type `one` or `two`, how would you infer this on the value param?

Comment: can you provide `setField` as well

Comment: Otherwise, does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdtAvFA3gKClYEDOwCMAXFHgE4CWcA5gNwZa7ABMxZlt92eAzK8BdToBfOmlCQoAFQDuAeyjJ0mLsF4l+7OssYAWPgI4i0aAGYBXOAGNg5WXBIRgASQAmAHklQIAD2xwXOFAA1hAgsiawCAB8ABQhIMSSADRQAG4AhgA2ZhDE8BAA2pIAugCUxKmy5C505lY2dg7O7p4+fgHBoeFScrHxiSkZ2bk9skVlFVU1phbWtvY4jq4eXr4Q-oHx3TH5UAA+o6V9oQNpWTnEOwj7h+OlqEJoQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @spender it seems that your approach is the desired one